# Made changes in Users but it revert back to same position in Odoo V10

Tags: xml, view, odoo, open-source, odoo-10

From users form view I want to hide a lot of unnecessary fields. So for that I tried deleting code, make them invisible etc. but all my hard work goes into vain. This irritates me a lot so is there any way I can keep the changes which I made.

For reference, I'll share the details.

**Current User view**

[image: Current User view]

I want to keep this view permanently but  after some instant, it is rolled back to its older version

[image: View]

**I'll be so thankful to you if you help me on this because currently, I am in big trouble. Thanks in advance**

Comment: Have you deleted this from The XML file or from debug mode?

Comment: I have done the both ways. It again restore to the previous version